# How to set an alarm even when app is killed? (Android 9)

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have implemented a simple app in order to set an alarm (e.g. 7.00pm) every minute. When running this app at emulator, which android version is 8.1, it runs successfully in background even the app is killed. But when running the same app at my android 9 when app is killed it stops running in background.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.context = this;
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if(alarmRunning == false) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
    }



}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

AlertReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int minutes=0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Service",String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
    intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    minutes++;
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 7);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);

    context.startActivity(intent);
    /*Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
    context.startService(background);*/
}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance!